# Bash - Adding a item to a textfile

Tags: bash, shell

I have a formatted textfile that contains the store item's details in such a format.

```
item:username:quantity:price
```

So it'll be like

```
Nike - Rucksack:testingabc:01:25.00
```

To allow the store owner to keep track of his items in the store.

I've tried the following code, but I would like to check if the item exists before entering it.

```
function addnewitem
{
echo -n "Item: " ; read ITEM
echo -n "Username: " ; read USERNAME

result="$(grep -q "$ITEM" ItemStored.txt)"
echo "$result"

if [ $result -eq "1"  ] ; then  
   echo "Error! Item already exists!"    
else 
echo -n "Quantity: " ; read QUANTITY
echo -n "PRICE : " ; read PRICE
echo "$ITEM:$USERNAME:$QUANTITY:$PRICE" >> ItemStored.txt ;
echo "New item '$ITEM' has been added successfully!"
fi
```

While entering, I get such an error though.  [: -eq: unary operator expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you needed is `-c` not `-q`:

```
result=$(grep -c "$ITEM" ItemStored.txt)
```

- When next to assignment, doublequotes are optional since word splitting doesn't occur in it.

The error was caused by `$result` not having any value (as `-q` of `grep` suppresses output) that your command becomes like

```
if [  -eq "1"  ] ; then
```

If you're in Bash as well, it's commendable that you use `[[ ]]` over `[ ]` as the former doesn't do things unnecessary with conditional expressions like word splitting and pathname expansion.

See [Word Splitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) and [Filename Expansion (prev. Pathname Expansion)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html)

Comment: But I'm still getting the same error though after I tried -c. Saying that unary operator expected.

Comment: @Zenix Run your script as `bash -x script.sh` and tell me the output.

Comment: It's fine, I solved it! What was missing was the "$result" -eq "1".